# Aninhar chaves de um array em um objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, array-multidimensional

Como criar um objeto javascript aninhado a partir de um array literal?

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
var x = ['a','b','c'];
```

A partir do array 'x' eu gostaria de gerar o objeto seguinte:

```
var y = {a:{b:{c:{}}}};
```

Até o momento tentei iterar dentro de um laço. Mas não encontro uma forma de validar se o resultado já existe ou não, nem colocar na posição correta, uma chave dentro de outra.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na biblioteca underscore.js. Ela facilita bastante nos tratamentos de arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazeres exatamente como pedes precisas iterar a array e ir criando sub objetos. Podes fazer assim:

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var y = {};
var temp = y;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    temp[x[i]] = {};
    temp = temp[x[i]];
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxq9108x/

Isto funciona porque em JavaScript podem passar-se objetos por referência entre variáveis. Assim quando faço `temp[x[i]] = {};` é o mesmo que fazer `y[x[i]] = {};` na primeira iteração.

Depois como faço `temp = temp[x[i]];` estou a mudar a referência de que parte do objeto a variável `temp` está a apontar. E vou assim criando os sub-objetos.

Comment: Era exatamente isso.

Comment: @MarceloAymone ótimo, fico contente de ter ajudado.

Comment: @Sergio Será que daria pra fazer isso com o `.reduce()`?

Comment: O único porém, é que se eu fizer isto dentro de outro laço, uma chave sobreescreve a outra...

Comment: @MaiconCarraro sim daria (http://jsfiddle.net/4jz3q4yk/)

Comment: @MarceloAymone como assim? Podes comentar com um exemplo no jsFiddle (usando o meu exemplo)?

Comment: Eu tava com dificuldade nisso @Sergio, não me atentei que tinha que passar o y no `}, y);`, eu tava atribuindo o retorno do reduce :~

Comment: É possível sim, basta declarar o Y fora dos laços de repetição. A idéia é criar arrays multidimensionais apartir de um array de objetos, sem repetir as chaves, mas usando o teu exemplo funcionou sim.